# Google map Markers

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to insert a google map in my application.

I want to mark the location from source to destination, both of them provided.

I am totally new to JavaScript so please help me with this.

The code that I'am using now is:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

        function initialize()
         {
             if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
            var polyline = new GPolyline([
            new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
            new GLatLng(37.4519, -122.1519)
            ], "#ff0000", 10);
            map.addOverlay(polyline);
            }
        }​​
</script>
```

How to import the google api related to this code?

Comment: You need to describe what isn't working

Comment: The terms 'source and destination' aren't used in your code, only the users current location. Do you get any console errors when you view your page? Have you verified init() is being called?

Comment: As of now i get a blank white screen..I guess i shall get the map once i import the required api..Not sure i no how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using API V2 because of `GMap2(...)`. In this case insert

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.google.com/mapsfile=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=KEY&amp;sensor=false">
</script>
```

into the `<head>` section of your HTML document. `KEY` is the Google API key that you can get from Google. However, it is better to **use version V3** of the API. Then you do not need the key. In V3 insert

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> 
</script>
```

into the `<head>` section of your HTML document.
See also the Google Map API v3 [tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html). In your document you should have a `<div id="map_canvas" ...></div>`. The map V3 is created as

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```